# Prioritising network bandwidth with Huawei E5172 router

Tags: internet, bandwidth, traffic, priority, network-traffic

I have [Huawei 5172](http://www.store4g.com/huawei-e5172/) router and I wonder is it possible to prioritise network bandwidth for some computers in my home network? By 'prioritise' I mean in a general way, not any specific protocol or application. I just want to be sure that one computer will always use all possible bandwidth, whether is it surfing, playing games or anything else. [Here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B05CtuPSMsUgOTNYc3Y2elRrYjg/view?usp=sharing) is the PDF file which is downloaded if I click 'help' when logged in to my router.

**EDIT**:
The only thing related to QoS which I found in linked PDF is to enable WMM. I did try to do this, but still after enabling it I cannot see anything which would give me an option to 'prioritise'.

Page related to this in router's admin interface:
[image]

Comment: Check if it provides any QOS options.

Comment: Updated my post with additional information related to QoS.